# unable to understand inc/dec operators behaviours in macros in c language

Tags: c++, c, macros

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define max(a) ((++a)*(++a)*(++a))
main(){
int a=5;
printf("%d\n",max(a));
printf("%d",a); }
```

this should return 6*7*8 but it is returning 7*7*8 why ?

Comment: [Undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to lack of [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

Comment: This is not really a macro issue. This is an issue with the resulting code, which would be bogus if you typed it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard says that you get undefined behavior if you modify variable multiple times between sequence points. That is what you do, so that is what you get.

Note that:

1) You have no promises about order of `(++a)*(++a)*(++a)` evaluation, apart from operation (multiply) being done after it's arguments calculation (++a).

2) You are explicitly not allowed to modify same variable more than once between sequence points.